# The difference between three possible translations of “rebuke”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, difference

I need to translate *rebuke* into German. It is a verb. There are three translations for that: *zurechtweisen, ermahnen, tadeln*. What is the difference between them?

Example:

> Peter rebuked to me that I didn’t do well in the project.

Comment: by the way, is there some German-German dictionary, with explanations that I could use?

Comment: If you considered a real book, I suggest Pons "Deutsch als Fremdsprache", one can look [here](http://de.pons.com/produkte/pons-grosswoerterbuch-deutsch-als-fremdsprache-978-3-12-517429-0) at some sample pages.

Comment: I do not thing that the example is correct English.

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/rebuke.html

Comment: For one, there are more than three possible translations. I'm missing "rügen", for instance. For another, you "rebuke somebody" and not "to somebody". And you usually rebuke somebody "for [not] (doing) something)". Your English sentence sounds a bit weird after all.

Answer (score 1):

*Tadeln* and *zurechtweisen* are synonyms and translate to *rebuke*.

*Ermahnen* rather means *warn* or *caution*.

Comment: Du würdest den Beispielsatz sowohl mit tadeln, als auch mit zurechtweisen übersetzen?

Comment: *Peter wies mich zurecht, dass ich nicht gut an dem Projekt gearbeitet hatte.*

Comment: Peter wies mich _dafür_ zurecht, dass … / Peter tadelte mich _dafür_, dass

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebuke)calls a rebuke to be a type of censure. Which in turn is a type of critique.

Peter kritisierte meine Projektleistung.